# Comparar elementos Dois a dois de um vetor

Tags: python-3.x

Boa tarde! Estou estudando python3 (sou bem iniciante), e gostaria de, dado um vetor, comparar os elementos deste vetor 2 a 2 para ver se são iguais.
exemplo:
[2,3,4,4,5]
o 2 compara com o 3, e temos que 2!=3
o 3 compara com o 4, e temos que 3!=4
o 4 compara com o 4, e temos que 4==4
o 4 compara com o 5, e temos que 4!=5

o que pensei foi algo do tipo

```
for x in vetor2:
   if vetor2[x]==vetor2[x+1]:
```

entretanto da out of range...
obrigado!

Comment: Basta iterar até o `length -1`.

Comment: Oi! E como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score -1):

Uma maneira de implementar seria:

```
vetor = [2,3,4,4,5]
for x in range(len(vetor)-1):
    if vetor[x]==vetor[x+1]:
        print('sim')
    else: 
        print('não')
```

Para este código utilizei as funções [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) e [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) que fazem parte `Built-in Functions` do Python.

### Explicando o código

A função `range` vai gerar uma sequência de números imutáveis até um valor.

Quando utilizado com um parâmetro do tipo inteiro, esta função vai gerar números até o valor passado como parâmetro (neste caso será o `len(vetor)-1`).

Já a função `len` retorna o número de items de um objeto (objeto aqui pode ser: string, array, list, tuple ou dictionary, tipos Python)

Comment: Obrigado!!! tentarei

Answer (score -2):

Poderia fazer assim:

```
for i in range(1, len(vetor2)):
    if vetor2[i]==vetor2[i-1]:
        print(vetor2[i])
```

Ou seja, começando a contar a partir de 1 (a primeira posição é o zero) e compara com o anterior (`i-1`)

Ou assim, limitando ao tamanho menos 1 (`len(vetor2)-1`) e comparanado com o próximo sem deixar passar do limite e dar o erro da sua pergunta.

```
for x in range(len(vetor2)-1):
    if vetor2[x]==vetor2[x+1]:
        print(vetor2[x])
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: @RômuloRebello se a resposta ajudou vote nela ou marque como certa, pq não ajudamos e tem gente que gosta de dar votos negativos sem "motivo aparente", o que desanima de ajudar